# Severity: Warning error in php page

Tags: php, codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

> Message: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the
>   system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In
>   case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this
>   warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We
>   selected 'Asia/Manila' for 'PHT/8.0/no DST' instead
>
> Filename: helpers/date_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 94

Why is everytime I run my php program I got this error? the code below is my currently codes.

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
        $date = date("d-M-y");
?>
```

Comment: set the timezone in the php.ini file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Set the timezone in the **php.ini** file on the server:

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Manila"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error doesn't match your code - per [the PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php) "Asia/Manila" is a supported value - It is possible that those warnings are either from a different call, or an older version.

Without calling [`date_default_timezone_set(...);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) with a valid timezone has PHP default to using the system time zone, which in your case appears to be reported as 'PHT/8.0/no DST', so you would either need to add the call to select the specific time zone in each page that has date/time functions, or better still, set the [`date.timezone` setting in your php.ini file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)